# No callbacks found for cron job analytics_subscribe

Tags: magento2.4, cron, exception

Magento 2.4.x

I have this exception in `var/log/cron.log`:

```
main.CRITICAL: Exception: No callbacks found for cron job analytics_subscribe in vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php:338
```

In table `cron_schedule` there are many rows with `job_code` 'analytics_subscribe', `status`= 'error' and `messages` = 'No callbacks found for cron job analytics_subscribe'.

Searching through the code (in `crontab.xml` files) there is no cron job with code `analytics_subscribe`.

Where is this cron job set and how to remove it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cron job comes from removed 'Magento_Analytics' module.
There is an entry in `core_config_data` table with `path` = `crontab/default/jobs/analytics_subscribe/schedule/cron_expr`.

Delete this row and Magento flush cache.
The error will not show anymore.

I did the same for job with code `analytics_collect_data`.
`path` in `core_config_data` is `crontab/default/jobs/analytics_collect_data/schedule/cron_expr`